# Can't get full dump using cmd:Invalid Username/Password error

Tags: oracle, export, dump

I'm trying to get a full dump of a certain database called HQBASE. I write the following command in cmd

```
exp userid=sys/123456 FULL=Y FILE=C:\HQ_FULL.DMP
```

but I get invalid username/password:logon denied error

If I connect to the database through SQLPLus or any other IDE with the same credentials I get no error and connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax may be wrong. I checked some examples and they suggest that user/password is the first parameter, without specifier:

```
exp sys/123456 FULL=Y FILE=C:\HQ_FULL.DMP
```

Comment: The `userid=` specifier is optional.

Comment: Thank you lots. It worked after changinig the sys password. However I was entering the password copied from the cmd command when using TOAD. Maybe it's because cmd exp command does not work with cerain types of passwords.

Comment: Some characters may cause trouble because of how the shell handles them. The space character is one of them. Others are characters that have different reresentation depending on codepage (windows has a history of using different code pages in windows than in the shell).